# None and (Who or that)

Tags: sentence-construction

> *There is none **who** can help you in this crucial moment of your career.*

Is there anything wrong with this sentence? 
My book says we should use **that** instead of **who** to improve the sentence and the rule given is 'After the words all, same, any, none, nothing, only and as, we should use that'.

But I think the sentence is fine as it is. Please clarify.

Comment: The "rule" cited is only a guideline. There are circumstances in which you would want to use "who". For example, "All who agree, say 'aye'. All opposed, say 'nay'."

Comment: It seems that on informal English you can put *that* instead of *who* or *which*, but you can't do that if you've been given a **non-defining relative clause.**

Comment: Abhi which book are you referring to ? Is it Mirror of common errors ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this ngram from Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=none%20who&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnone%20who%3B%2Cc0), "none who" has become less common over the years, suggesting that it may be quite old-fashioned. You could say:

> There is **no one** who can help you in this crucial moment of your career.

or

> There is **nobody** who can help you in this crucial moment of your career.

(not exactly informal, but "no one" is more common in formal situations.)

Comment: "There is none who" definitely sounds a little archaic to me. I think it sounds a little more natural to use "none" by itself as the subject, as in "None think it wise." It still doesn't sound conversational though- in my mind it sounds like a line out of Tolkien.

Comment: *No one* sounds much better than *nobody* in this sentence.